# Cassandra Version 3.11.4, then Connection refused problem

Tags: cassandra

I installed Cassandra Version 3.11.4, then changed the cassandra.yaml file to listen_address and rpc_address set to my IP address but there is a Connection refused problem. How to resolved this issue?

Comment: I would start with validating cassandra is running (ps -ef | grep cassandra). Also check the port (assuming 9042 - (netstat -nap | grep 9042)). Assuming Cassandra is up and running and something is listening on the listen port, what and where are you trying to connect from (e.g. cqlsh on the local host?). You may have to use: cqlsh -u <youruser> -p <yourpass> -h <yourhostIP> -p <yourport>.  Update the thread with the output.

Comment: Have you checked port 9042 is opened? give the host name and port too while connecting CQLSH.  bin/cqlsh [-u user -p password] [host [port]] .

Comment: `nc -z host 9042` or telnet